# Azure 'Application error' when trying to run Django Web App

Tags: azure, docker, django-apps

Trying to host my Django app on Azure however I received the following errors. I also have an sqlite database but I dont think that causes the error if I'm not mistaken. I have set the DOCKER_REGISTRY... within Azure config to match those of my Docker account, is that correct?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Azure has confirmed the below is successful:
[image]

I have tried the following from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/168746/container-didn39t-respond-to-http-pings-on-port-80.html), [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1003418/azure-docker-app-error-site-did-not-start-within-expected-time-limit-and-co), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60709004/microsoft-azure-app-service-for-containers-docker-problem) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58495639/running-a-docker-container-in-azure-web-app-didnt-respond-to-http-pings-on-por). I thought the issue was to do with the exposed ports set within docker file or within the apps settings.py file.

**settings.py** snippets

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.herokuapp.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'shawjournal.azurewebsites.net']

WEBSITES_PORT=80
PORT=9000
```

**dockerfile**

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.8

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 9000

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

# Copy project
COPY . /code/

CMD ["python", "/code/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following-up [on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1125963/index.html), I understand you have referred to multiple threads/solutions on this. If you haven't reviewed these already, please try these:

From the initial investigation, I see that you’re exposing multiple different ports.
By default, App Service assumes your custom container is listening on port 80. If your container listens to a different port set it using this App Setting.
E.g., 8000. ||  I see you have added port 9000 and 8000 in a few settings.

Just to highlight the difference: app settings/variable- `PORT` (default) vs WEBSITES_PORT (it’s for custom containers).

This doc shows [supported and unsupported Docker Compose configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#unsupported-options) options ( build (not allowed))

Checkout the  [App Service Django samples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/tutorial-custom-container?pivots=container-linux&tabs=azure-cli) and steps outlined in this doc [Django Deployment on App Service Linux](https://azureossd.github.io/2022/02/20/Django-Deployment-on-App-Service-Linux/index.html#container-doesnt-start) for more info.